# What does the verb "curdle" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "the Hindu" which was:

At that time, a strange melange of emotions - feelings of grief, despair, shame, nostalgia curdled up.

I couldn't find any satisfying meaning of curdle in this context in most of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curdled up literally means to *thicken something* like curd.
Here, it means that the mixture of emotions is heavy for the person to handle. Like he is feeling those emotions in extreme levels and all of them being mixed up is hard for him to take in.